# Is it okay to carry a small titanium souvenir in baggage

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, luggage, india

So I made this small titanium miniature of Captain America shield for my girlfriend who's travelling to the US, she was wondering if they'll allow that in baggage/carry in.

It's a small 38 mm dia and 0.8mm thick disc of titanium with blunt edges. Preferable to put it in baggage though.

Comment: It's about the size of a large coin. I can't see why that would be a problem. The monetary value won't be enough for it to be a problem at US customs either.

Comment: Depends. Will you also have any *Ant Man* paraphernalia?

Comment: Haha. No Ant Man paraphernalia for now.

Comment: The item did go through successfully though. Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason why a titanium miniature *that* small would raise any eyebrows. Titanium & titanium alloy are used to manufacture golf clubs, eyeglass frames, water bottles, etc., and it is hard to imagine that titanium alone would cause any suspicion.

Answer (score 1):

You should check with the security. I had to throw my guitar key when is used to tighten the guitar neck in trash. When they found in scanning machine that there was some metal inside my bag. so double check before flying there can be some restrictions to metal objects.

Answer (score 0):

If it small enough and if it looks harmless enough you should be fine putting it in your carry-on luggage. However, if you want to be sure that it will not be taken away by airport security you should follow the golden rule and put in in hold luggage.

Comment: Anything valuable and/or precious should be carried in carry-on luggage. Or even in a well sealed pocket!